# Python3 - Formatting csv output the right way

Tags: python, python-3.x

**What I'm trying to do is:**

- Process a csv datafile with device information
- Filter and print these based on user input

**csv Data:**

```
HostXYZ1;Device IP;Interface name;Generic Server
HostXYZ2_very long hostname;Device IP;Interface name;Generic Server
HostXYZ3;Device IP;Very long interface name;Generic Server
```

Main part of the script:

```
input = sys.argv[1]


cprint('          Hostname                |     IP-Address      |       Interface               |        Device Type                    ', 'white', 'on_grey')
cprint('-'*128, 'white', 'on_grey')


with open('inventory.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        if (input.lower() in row[0].lower()) or (input in row[1].lower()) or (input.lower() in row[2].lower()):
            if len(row[0]) <= 13:
                if len(row[1]) <= 13:
                    print(" " + row[0] + "\t                 --   " + row[1] + "\t   --   " + row[2] + "\t  --\t   " + row[3])
                elif len(row[1]) == 14:
                    print(" " + row[0] + "\t                 --   " + row[1] + "   --   " + row[2] + "\t  --\t   " + row[3])    
                elif len(row[1]) == 15:
                    print(" " + row[0] + "\t                 --   " + row[1] + "  --   " + row[2] + "\t  --\t   " + row[3]) 
            else:
                if len(row[1]) <= 13:
                    print(" " + row[0] + "  --   " + row[1] + "\t   --   " + row[2] + "\t  --\t   " + row[3])
                elif len(row[1]) == 14:
                    print(" " + row[0] + "  --   " + row[1] + "   --   " + row[2] + "\t  --\t   " + row[3])    
                elif len(row[1]) == 15:
                    print(" " + row[0] + "  --   " + row[1] + "  --   " + row[2] + "\t  --\t   " + row[3])
```

My main problem is that the length of the data in any of the columns can vary and I couldn't figure out a way to print out the result nicely, just by stacking if statements based on the length of the string; which is not scalable...

The output I would like to see:

```
          Hostname                |     IP-Address      |       Interface               |        Device Type                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     HostXYZ1                    ---    Device IP      ---    Interface name           ---    Generic Server
     HostXYZ2_very long hostname ---    Device IP      ---    Interface name           ---    Generic Server
     HostXYZ3                    ---    Device IP      ---    Very long interface name ---    Generic Server
```

Is there a way to do this in a more Pythonic way, where it doesn't matter the length of the data I have; it still prints it out nicely tabbed?

***Update:
"How to Pretty Print a CSV file in Python" isn't an answer as its not the best pythonic way possible; for that to work, you need to add a completely new script to your own...

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323715/python-evenly-space-output-data-with-varying-string-lengths

Comment: Can I get some help how to convert this to my case?

Comment: do you have an idea of the approximate max length in each of the columns? if so, it is easy, just use that number like {:20s} for 20 characters or whatever number for your specific case and do this for all the six columns. so it could look something like {:20s} {:22s} etc. Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/33323724/435089

Comment: I'm using this: {:<32}  ---  {:<15}  ---  {:<20}  ---  {:<20}; but I dont know whats the max it can be. Is there a way to make this dynamic?

Comment: does it work? why are you having the less than symbol? also, you need to have "s" at the end of the number if the column is a string, "f" if it is a float and "d" if the column has integer values

Comment: an approximate max number is sufficient, one that could make your output look tidy

Comment: I think I've got it. Thanks for the help :)