# how do i print the 2d list as an even table?

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

```
#Create a program that allows 2 players to throw a 6 sided dice and record the roll value 10 times. 
#The winner is the player with the highest total 
#This task must store the results in a 2D array 

#Extra: 
#Work out the average roll across the 10 throws per player and display the result 
#Frequency analysis broken down per player and per game

from random import randint

results = [[],[]]

for i in range (2):
    
    player = []
    total = 0
    average = 0
    
    #player enters their name
    name = input(f"\nEnter your name player {i + 1}: ")
    player.append(name)
    
    print(f"Player {i + 1} it is your turn")
    
    for x in range(10):
        print("\nTo roll the die press any key")
        input()
    
        roll = randint(1,6)
        player.append(roll)
        print("You rolled a", roll)
        total += roll
    
    average = total/10
    
    player.append(total)
    player.append(average)
    results.append(player)
    
print("""\nNAME  R1  R2  R3  R4  R5  R6  R7  R8  R9  R10  TOTAL  AVG""")

for i in results:
    for c in i:
        print(c,end = "   ")
    print()
```

im not sure how to evenly space out the values so they are in line when they are printed.

i tried adding spaces inbetween the values when printing but if one of the names or numbers are a different length then the whole row becomes unaligned with the column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Evenly space output data with varying string lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323715/python-evenly-space-output-data-with-varying-string-lengths)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax:

```
print('%5s' % str(c))
```

Basically:

- the `%` character informs python it will have to substitute something
  to a token
- the `s` character informs python the token will be a string
- the `5` (or whatever number you wish) informs python to pad the string
  with spaces up to 5 characters.

I found that on [How to print a string at a fixed width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450472/how-to-print-a-string-at-a-fixed-width).

Comment: it printed the values vertically instead of in one row

Comment: answer does not give desired output. another user commented already

Answer (score -1):

to calculate difference between 2 names

```
diff = abs(len(results[2][0]) - len(results[3][0])) #abs = absolute value
```

compare 2 lengths of names:

```
if len(results[2][0] ) > len(results[3][0]):
    results[3][0] = results[3][0] + " "*diff # add spaces much as difference between 2 names
else:
    results[2][0] = results[2][0] + " "*diff
```

Comment: This will not handle cases where the string (names in the case of the question) are not equal in length.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, now changed, I guess(and hope) now there are no problems

Comment: it didnt work for me

Comment: check again,  I tried this in your code and worked