# Need help showing a dictionary evenly

Tags: python

My problem is when I try to display the contents from a dictionary, I have a colon between the keys and the values, but the keys are not even which makes it look sloppy.

This is the code I tried:

```
thisdict =      {
    "Fuji Apples": "0.94",
    "Honeycrisp Apples": "1.54",
    "Gala Apples": "0.84",
    "Envy Apples": "1.60",
    "Red Delicious Apples": "1.00",
    "Granny Smith Apples": "1.06",
    "Pink Lady Apples": "0.99",
    "Jazz Apples": "0.99",
    "Cosmic Crisp Apples": "1.18",
    "Opal Apples": "0.87",
    "SugarBee Apples": "2.27",
    "Golden Delicious Apples": 1.24
}
for x, y in thisdict.items():
    print(x, ":", y)
```

The product of the code:

```
Fuji Apples : 0.94

Honeycrisp Apples : 1.54

Gala Apples : 0.84

Envy Apples : 1.60

Red Delicious Apples : 1.00

Granny Smith Apples : 1.06

Pink Lady Apples : 0.99

Jazz Apples : 0.99

Cosmic Crisp Apples : 1.18

Opal Apples : 0.87

SugarBee Apples : 2.27

Golden Delicious Apples : 1.24
```

I would like the colons to be in a straight line but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Use tabs. `\t`.

Comment: Use string formatting to print the first string with a fixed width.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Evenly space output data with varying string lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323715/python-evenly-space-output-data-with-varying-string-lengths) also [Python spacing and aligning strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623727/python-spacing-and-aligning-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a format string to accomplish this:

```
thisdict = {
    "Fuji Apples": "0.94",
    "Honeycrisp Apples": "1.54",
    "Gala Apples": "0.84",
    "Envy Apples": "1.60",
    "Red Delicious Apples": "1.00",
    "Granny Smith Apples": "1.06",
    "Pink Lady Apples": "0.99",
    "Jazz Apples": "0.99",
    "Cosmic Crisp Apples": "1.18",
    "Opal Apples": "0.87",
    "SugarBee Apples": "2.27",
    "Golden Delicious Apples": 1.24
}
longest_key_length = max(list(map(lambda x: len(x), thisdict.keys())))
for x, y in thisdict.items():
    print(f"{x:<{longest_key_length}} : {y}")
```

Result:

```
Fuji Apples             : 0.94
Honeycrisp Apples       : 1.54
Gala Apples             : 0.84
Envy Apples             : 1.60
Red Delicious Apples    : 1.00
Granny Smith Apples     : 1.06
Pink Lady Apples        : 0.99
Jazz Apples             : 0.99
Cosmic Crisp Apples     : 1.18
Opal Apples             : 0.87
SugarBee Apples         : 2.27
Golden Delicious Apples : 1.24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first go through the keys to find the longest one, then create a format string to suit that. That would go something like:

```py
def pretty(my_dict):
    sz = max([len(_) for _ in my_dict.keys()])
    fmt_string = "{{:{}}} : {{:5.2f}}".format(sz)
    for key, val in my_dict.items():
        print(fmt_string.format(key, float(val)))


thisdict =      {
    "Fuji Apples": "0.94",
    "Honeycrisp Apples": "1.54",
    "Gala Apples": "0.84",
    "Envy Apples": "1.60",
    "Red Delicious Apples": "1.00",
    "Granny Smith Apples": "1.06",
    "Pink Lady Apples": "0.99",
    "Jazz Apples": "0.99",
    "Cosmic Crisp Apples": "1.18",
    "Opal Apples": "0.87",
    "SugarBee Apples": "2.27",
    "Golden Delicious Apples": 1.24
}

pretty(thisdict)
```

The output of that is:

```
Red Delicious Apples    :  1.00
Jazz Apples             :  0.99
Cosmic Crisp Apples     :  1.18
Pink Lady Apples        :  0.99
Honeycrisp Apples       :  1.54
Granny Smith Apples     :  1.06
Gala Apples             :  0.84
SugarBee Apples         :  2.27
Opal Apples             :  0.87
Envy Apples             :  1.60
Fuji Apples             :  0.94
Golden Delicious Apples :  1.24
```